# How to install sudo commands in Jupyterlab and What is the password for user jovyan?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I am using [Jupyterlab](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/try.jupyter.org?urlpath=lab) for python project. When I give this command in terminal sudo apt-get install chromium-browser. It's asking password.

```
[sudo] password for jovyan:
```

I tried without sudo "apt-get install chromium-browser", still I am getting error. How do I resolve it?

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```